# jsPlumb: How to get an element after "mouseup" event is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '.agent-wrapper', function(info){
  console.log(info);    // It works fine
  console.log(this);    // It works fine too
});
```

`.agent-wrapper` is an element-wrapper for all jsPlumb objects.

```
$(document).on('mouseup', 'div.node', function(info){
  console.log(info);    // It doesn't work
  console.log(this);    // It doesn't work too
});
```

How can I receive the element-node inside the jsPlumb-wrapper for "mouseup" event.

**HTML**

```
<div id="flume-AGENT-1" class="agent-wrapper" index="0">
  <div data-nodetype="source" class="w node jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable">
    Element 1
    <div class="ep"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-nodetype="source" class="w node jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable">
    Element 2
    <div class="ep"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i "mousedown" a cursor on 1-st element and "mouseup" it on second element - i cant get an element target in JavaScript. ... How to get event.target.

Seems like jsPlumb unbind all events related to elements that are located inside its wrapper ... but i need to receive this element. How?

Comment: Can we see some HTML?

Comment: Added some HTML with my explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have bind those ".node" div's with jsPlumb **source** or **target** methods which will override jQuery mouse-up and mouse-down. Because jsPlumb handles the connection creation on that particular ".node" div on mouse events.

Hence you cannot bind both jsPlumb and jQuery events on same elements, you need to handle those events on parent node as you did on ".agent-wrapper".